Svelte Component with Internal Store per Instance connected with Props?
I have a parent component with many descendant components that need to access its values, ideally those values come from props that the app using the parent component can supply. I finally managed to get it to work via Reactive Stores, but it's verbose and feels like there should be a better solution. This is the parent component:
<script>
  import { setContext } from 'svelte';
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

  export let data = [];
  const _data = writable(data);
  $: $_data = data;
  
  export let mode = 'view';
  const _mode = writable(mode);
  $: $_mode = mode;

  ...
  ...
  ...

  setContext('parent-component',{
    data: _data,
    mode: _mode,
    ...
    ...
  });
</script>

This way the data and other props can be passed in through the requesting Svelte component via <ParentComponent data={localData} mode={'editor'} ... /> and the child components can be reactively updated via const {data, mode, ...} = getContext('parent-component') on an as-needed basis.
The problem is that the parent component, essentially serving as a component constructor, gets fairly long for all the props that need to be passed in. And that would've been fine, but this method of passing the stores down, while ensuring each component has its own instance of store values, feels really long.
Appreciate any suggestions on what could be a better approach, or maybe this is the most succinct way for now.

I may not be understanding your question but can you not just bind the props sent in the parent? This should make them reactive and let you modify them in the child component. <Child bind:data />

@Avi4nFLu Thanks for the question. The problem with binding is that descendant components are complex and nested, so it would be a lot of unnecessary binding hell for the many layers in between the parent and the final receiving leaf component.

If I am understanding your question correctly you can fix this issue by making a file in lib named store.js. It should look something like this:
import { writable } from "svelte/store"

export const numberPropStore= writable(1)
export const objectPropStore = writable({})
export const booleanPropStore = writable(false)
export const stringPropStore = writable("")

In the store I like to name my variables with "Store" at the end so when I use them in my components I know they are being saved in store.js. Then you can access these variables inside any component you need to and set the values. This way they are also reactive so if you update the value in one component you can see the updated values in any other component. These do not even have to be parent/child components. In order to view/change values you need to add a $ before the variable
component1
<script>
import { numberPropStore, objectPropStore, booleanPropStore, stringPropStore } from '$lib/store';

function handleClick() {
        $stringPropStore = 'You clicked the button!';
    }

</script>

<button on:click={() => {
            $booleanPropStore = false;
            $numberPropStore += 1;
            handleButtonClick
        }}>Tracker</button
    >


component2
<script>
import { numberPropStore, objectPropStore, booleanPropStore, stringPropStore } from '$lib/store';

</script>

<div>{$booleanPropStore}</div>
<div>{$numberPropStore }</div>
<div>{$stringPropStore }</div>

I hope this helps and answers the question and that you didn't already know this 

Appreciate the attempt, @Avi4nFlu. Two things don't solve the issue I have here, which is that the parent component of say component1 and component2 in your example, will need to have its own store and that values need to be passed through the parent component.

Specifically ParentComponent may be created multiple times with different values, so the children component1 and component2 will be reactive to different instances of ParentComponent. Then, when supplying prop values to ParentComponent via , ParentComponent will need to provide an export let ____. Ideally component1 and component2 can use stores like you've pointed out, but work off prop instance values from ParentComponent.

Ah, I see now. Sorry I wasn't helpful. I do have one more idea which also probably won't help. How are you creating ParentComponent? Is it being created with a loop? And do you know how many parent components are being created, or at least the max number of components being created? You could have multiple store values and set a store value based on the index. Then you could send the index value to the child to let the child know which store value to use. You also could have multiple stores and pass some prop to a child to know which store you need to access.
